# Having trouble targeting a single input among multiple elements with the same class name (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, targeting

I have a page with a list of `li` elements, each called `.section`. The page starts with just one section, but the user can add more with a click. Each section has a dropdown called `.wip-location` and three input fields called `.section-number`, `.section-name`, and `.section-description`. (The -number and -description inputs are irrelevant but I included them here just in case they are causing problems.)

Every time the dropdown is changed, I'd like the selected text to get filled into the `.section-name` input.

This works the first time (when there is only one `.section`, `.wip-location`, and `.section-name` on the page), but as soon as the user adds more `.section`s, it appears that Jquery is unable to figure out which element to act upon, and no inputs are filled.

**HTML**

```
<li class="section">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 text-sm-right">Section Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input class="section-number" type="number" step="0.01" min="1" />
        </div>

        <label class="col-sm-2 text-sm-right">Section Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input class="section-name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 text-sm-right">Section Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <textarea class="section-description" />
        </div>

        <label class="col-sm-2 text-sm-right">WIP Location</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WipLocation,
                                        new SelectList(Model.WipLocations, "Key", "Value"),
                                        "-- select --",
                                        new { @class = "wip-location" })
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Automatically add Wip Location choice to Section Name input
$('.wip-location').change(function () {
    var $location = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
    var $section = $(this).closest('.section');
    var $sectionName = $section.find('.section-name');

    $sectionName.val($location);
});
```

As I said, when there is only one `.section` and `.wip-location` on the page, it works perfectly. I suspect jQuery gets confused when there are multiple `.wip-location`s or something, but I'm not sure if that's really the problem or how to fix it.

Comment: Use event delegation to attach event to dynamically created element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is dynamically added you could try to call the event like this:

`$(document).on('change', '.wip-location', function(){/*...*/})`